# Mongodb WeekofMonth?

Tags: mongodb, date-format, mongodb-aggregation

I am stuck with achieving `weekofMonth` instead of `WeekofYear`. Can somebody guide me on how to get this right?

```
db.activity.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {
                week: { $week: "$createdAt" }, 
                month: { $month: "$createdAt" },      
                year: { $year: "$createdAt" } 
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
     },
     { $match : { "_id.year" : 2016, "_id.month" : 5 } }
])
```

**Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "week" : 19,
        "month" : 5,
        "year" : 2016
    },
    "count" : 133.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "week" : 18,
        "month" : 5,
        "year" : 2016
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}
```

In the above shown data, it is actually not displaying `weekofMonth`. How can I get this given week 18 is the first week of Month?

Answer (score 5):

The **$week** operator gives you the week of year as [described in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/week/#exp._S_week).

The week of month can be calculated by getting the day of month and dividing by 7.

```
db.activity.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        "year": {$year: "$createdAt"},
        "month": {$month: "$createdAt"},
        "weekOfMonth": {$floor: {$divide: [{$dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"}, 7]}}
    }},
    {$group: {
        "_id": {"year": "$year", "month": "$month", "weekOfMonth": "$weekOfMonth"},
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }},
    {$match : { "_id.year" : 2016, "_id.month" : 5}}
])
```

Note that the week of month here is 0 based. If you want it to start at 1 just [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#exp._S_add) 1. Also, the [$floor](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/floor/) operator is new in version 3.2.

**Edit**

You can simulate the floor using [$mod](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) (which exists in version 3.0)

```
"weekOfMonth": {$subtract: [{$divide: [{$dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"}, 7]}, {$mod: [{$divide: [{$dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"}, 7]}, 1]}]},
```

Comment: Answer is true, but my server is deployed with version 3.0.2, doing at application Level, thanks for quick response another question inside $match i need to pass few more query params which is like this. childid: req.params.childid, word:{$in:["BAT","CAT"]} after passing this i am not getting any output and error even. @joao

Comment: @user1099855 after the $project stage those fields disappear. You either also add them to the $project or do a $match at the very beginning (which is recommended because of index usage).

Comment: @user1099855 check my edit, you can use $mod (works with version 3.0) instead of $floor to achieve the same result.